# How to get rid of sharp ticks/clicks when amplifying sound

Tags: audio-recording, sound-effects, noise, amplifier, clicks

I am amplifying an audio file frame-by-frame via the following algorithm:

1. Find maximum value among all the samples in a frame
2. Find the amplification factor to make the maximum value equal to 0 dB
3. Multiply the entire frame by the above amplification factor

The above algorithm makes many samples close to 0 dB in the signal (as expected). However, when played, those samples which are close to 0 dB create a very sharp tick or click. The signal is full of such sharp ticks/clicks drastically deteriorating the listening experience.

How to avoid generating such ticks/clicks?

**Edit: Tetsujin's method given in the 1st comment (to change the amplitude from 0 dB to -0.3 dB) seems to have reduced some of the clicks. But there are abundant clicks remaining at frame boundaries. I changed the amplitude from 0 dB to -0.3 dB to -1 dB to -3 dB to -10 dB but the clicks do not seem to go away. What should I do now? I have tried to read and look up what all of you were discussing but due to my limited knowledge, I couldn't see how should I go about implementing those things in my code. Could you please help me with what exactly should I do to reduce the "intersample/interframe clipping"?**

Comment: Don't normalise to 0dB, normalise to -0.3

Comment: Also, amplifying by frame leaves you with an issue at frame borders - your process adds in high freq, potentially high amplitude signals...

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks a lot, it worked. Could you please explain why it works? Also, I would be grateful if you could add your comment as an Answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Thanks for your expert comments, I am new to Audio Processing. Could you please help me with what I should do instead? I want as high amplification as possible and the different parts of the signal have different amplitudes.

Comment: IIRC, You need to interpolate the value based on the previous frame and the next one to avoid intersample clipping.

Comment: @rory not just at frame borders, surely the different loudness per frame would cause some interference all by itself, at a frequency correlated to the duration of a frame(i.e. inconsistent hi freq tremolo). I don't think interpolating a few samples between frames would solve this. Better to use a dynamic range processor.

Comment: @marc - the issue is not at frame borders, but it is caused by them. You end up with a series of peaks across the frequency domain. Not so much tremolo.

Comment: I can't add an answer yet, because Rory & Marc have some very valid points. Mine was just a global 'don't hit the top or it will bang' comment; equally important is the amount of hard breathing that's going to happen using your method.

Comment: Could you not use a compressor, to compress the signal, then amplify ?

Comment: I think the answer here is; to get rid of the clicks, (which _is_ the question)use @tets advice, but generally, what the OP is doing is a bad idea, due to the frame border issue and also because it opens the door to interference due to the signals that are inevitably created by consistent cyclic amplitude changes.

Comment: @MarcW Tetsujin's method seems to have reduced some of the clicks. But there clearly are abundant clicks remaining at frame boundaries. I changed the amplitude from 0 dB to -0.3 dB to -1 dB to -3 dB to -10 dB but the clicks do not seem to go away. What should I do now? I have tried to read and look up what all of you were discussing but due to my limited knowledge, I couldn't see how should I go about implementing those things in my code. Could you please help me with what exactly should I do to reduce the "intersample/interframe clipping".

Comment: Clicks occur whenever a sudden, extreme change in amplitude occurs over a one or a few samples. To avoid clicking, you need to make your volume changes gradual by, say, having all your frames overlap by 100 samples and crossfading them. Still, I'll repeat what everyone else is saying: use a compressor. Even if you manage to eliminate the clicking, this method will still produce (sonically) bad results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly your normalization factor will be different frame to frame. I cannot think of the application you will be using this for as it will create discontinuities across frame boundaries and introduce artifacts.

Additionally, your method doesn't take into account inter-sample peaks. You are normalizing only the visible peaks but in reality - once the audio has been converted back to analogue - you may experience clipping in the audio waveform between the samples. You need to up-sample your audio to at least 4x the original sampling rate in order to cover for inter-sample peaks.

You should not change the normalization factor on a frame-by-frame basis but you should scan all the audio and then apply a gross normalization factor across the whole file.

In my honest opinion your efforts are pointless. There is no reason to do what you are doing. You should not be normalizing audio to the highest possible level as all you are doing is increasing overall loudness and increasing the noise floor along with the signal.

A more useful exercise would be to normalize to a known loudness (LKFS) factor.

Comment: Plus, if you really want to adjust the dynamic range, use a dynamic range compressor. Much easier.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg has a module called `loudnorm` which *nearly* does what you are describing. However, the change is applied *incrementally* on a frame of 100ms. So the gain factor will change only a little bit one way or the other between each 100ms of audio samples.

The module is capable of detecting the loudness of the samples found so far in the file. It does so with an energy histogram. The pertinent line is:

```
// found in libavfilter/ebur128.c
++st->d->block_energy_histogram[find_histogram_index(sum)];
```

The issue here is that this histogram does not ever decay... so near the end of the file, it adjusts the loudness as if the whole file was measured first and it means the beginning of the file was adjusted *improperly*.

However, I think that you could apply an energy decay on the energy histogram. A simple decrement once every 100ms *after some time as passed* (i.e. after 3 sec., for example). This would require you to memorize the increments 3 sec. earlier so as to be able to apply the decrements later (i.e. cancel the effects of the noise generated 3 sec. ago).

Further, if you look at the acceptable parameters, this algorithm will allow you to specify a level between -5dB and -70dB. They do not let you increase the volume to 0dB. That's a crazy value anyway (and even -0.3dB is way too high).